# What does the chance calculated for an Ancient Hunt mean exactly?

Tags: minecraft-dungeons

When sacrificing some gear for the *Ancient Hunt*, you get a percentage and a number with a ~value, which can be increased using Enchantment Points, like the screenshot below:

[image]
<sub>(Courtesy of [04AM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7B11Vmf0u0&ab_channel=04AM))</sub>

In this case we have (and this is explained by the tooltip):

- 91% chance to **encounter** any Ancient mob
- ~2.2 Ancient mobs **on average**

But how should I read those numbers?
Do I have 91% chance to encounter any Ancient mob, hence 9% to find none?
It's not clear if that chance is referred to the whole level, or a single floor, or a single Hunt Door.
If I'm lucky enough to end into that percentage, what does exactly ~2.2 mean? I know it's an average number, so it could get, I guess, 1-4 Ancient mobs. I suppose the odds of getting more or less than that value are completely random.

Moreover, for what I can see, not every Hunt Door is activated during the Hunt. Are the door odds affected by these numbers?

If anyone out there have figured out something about this, I'd appreciate.